# Error 1067 for MySQL 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows-server-2008-r2, logfile, mysql-error-1067

I had installed MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 before 2 months and it's working till now. But suddenly MySQL Service goes down and I am not able to restart the service. 
Error Message:

```
121120 14:33:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121120 14:33:31 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121120 14:33:31 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121120 14:33:31 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121120 14:33:31 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.0G
121120 14:33:31 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 95420416 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 224395264 bytes!
121120 14:33:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
121120 14:33:31 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
121120 14:33:31 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
121120 14:33:31 [ERROR] Aborting

121120 14:33:31 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 95420416 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 224395264 bytes!
```

What you can do is search for that .cnf file and change the bytes from `224395264` to `95420416`

Mayby that helps....

**UPDATE**
as mentiod here: [Change InnoDB Log File Size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size)

Can you delete the log file ( .\ib_logfile0 ) when the server isn't running, and then the problem souldn't be there anymore...

Comment: Go into the .cnf file and search for the string that holds the size of that other file... So search for 224395264 and change it then...

Comment: @SaharshShah, also, check this out... [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size)

Comment: I had changed this variable: innodb_log_file_size=214M. Still I am not able to start the MySQL Service.

Comment: Thanks It's working. But I want to know which type of content that file has? Can you explain it?

Comment: @SaharshShah, By default, InnDB uses a shared "tablespace," which is one or more files from a single logical storage area. All InnoDB tables are stored together within the tabespace (from all the databases). 
By default, InnoDB creates two 5MB log files in the data directory: iblogfile0 and iblogfile1. The information is logged in circular fashion, with old information at the front of the log being overwritten when the log fills up.. Consequently, a larger log allows InnoDB to run longer without having to force changes recorded in the logs to be applied to the tablespace on disk.